# Indent figure multi-line caption

Tags: captions

```
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.55\textwidth]{Chapters/AIntroBackground/figures/Rayleigh.pdf}
\caption{Graph of intensity of the diffraction pattern for a circular aperture. Note that, similar to a single slit, the central maximum is wider and brighter than those to the sides.}
\label{fig:Rayleigh}
\end{figure}
```

[image: 1]

How can I indent the multi-line captoins. For example, I want to bring in the "similar" (2nd line)  right under "Graph" (1st line).

Comment: If not, use parbox starting with Graph.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

With the `caption` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
%   \captionsetup{format=hang}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\begin{document}
   \begin{figure}[htbp]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.55\textwidth]{lion.jpg}
        \captionsetup{format=hang}
        \caption{The lion (Panthera leo) is one of the four big cats in the genus Panthera and a member of the family Felidae. With some males exceeding 250 kg (550 lb) in weight, it is the second-largest living cat after the tiger.}
        \label{fig:Rayleigh}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

It is possible to set the option locally by placing `\captionsetup` in the same environment that contains the figure, or globally, by placing it in the preamble (commented in the MWE).