# Figure with multi-line Caption Indent (not "hang")

Tags: captions

I want an indent for my figure captions of 1 cm (left and right). In a [related](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/149752/indent-figure-multi-line-caption) question it was shown how `\captionsetup{format=hang}` can be used to indent the text, but not the initial "Figure 1: ".

I would like to have a figure caption, where the whole caption including the initial "Figure 1:" is indented. If possible, i would also like to size of the indent (in pixels or centimeter). How would that be possible?

Comment: `\captionsetup{width=\dimexpr\textwidth-2cm\relax}` should do the trick.

Comment: Bernard, thank you that is great, that's exactly what i need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some explanations on how to do that.

The simplest is to use the `caption` package and either set the key `width=\dimexpr\textwidth-2cm\relax`(sets the indent to 1cm) or set the key `margin=1cm` with `\captionsetup`. Note that if you want different left and right indent, you have to set, say, `margin={2cm,0cm}` (2cm indent on the left side, noindent on the right side).

Another possibility is the `\ffigbox{caption}{figure}` command from `floatrow`. It accepts as an optional argument the width of the float box. An interesting length is `\FBwidth`, which is the natural width of the object. This allows for adjusting the caption width as a relative value. Also, the same construction can be done for tables with the command `\ttabbox{caption}{table}.

Last possibility: load `threeparttable`. It defines a `measuredfigure` environment which sets the caption width to the figurewidth, exactly as the `threepartable` environment does for tables. Note that unfortunately, this mechanism is broken if you also load `floatrow.

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand{\ShowFrameLinethickness}{0.3pt}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{floatrow, caption}%
\captionsetup{labelfont=sc}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!h]
  \centering\captionsetup{width =\dimexpr\textwidth-2cm}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.7]{SanRomano}
  \caption{Paolo Uccello (1397–1475). \emph{The Counterattack of Michelotto da Cotignola at the battle of San Romano} (c. 1455), wood panel, 182 $ × $317, Musée du Louvre, Paris}
  \label{fig:label1}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!h]
  \centering\captionsetup{margin=2cm}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.7]{SanRomano}
  \caption{Paolo Uccello (1397–1475). \emph{The Counterattack of Michelotto da Cotignola at the battle of San Romano} (c. 1455), wood panel, 182 $ × $317, Musée du Louvre, Paris}
  \label{fig:label2}
\end{figure}

\clearpage

\begin{figure}[!h]
  \centering
  \ffigbox[1.1\FBwidth]{\caption{Paolo Uccello (1397–1475). \emph{The Counterattack of Michelotto da Cotignola at the battle of San Romano} (c. 1455), wood panel, 182 $ × $317, Musée du Louvre, Paris}\label{fig:label3}}%
  {\includegraphics[scale=0.8]{SanRomano}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Here is a code with `measuredfigure`:

```
\begin{figure}[!h]
  \centering
  \begin{measuredfigure}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.8]{SanRomano}
    \caption{Paolo Uccello (1397–1475). \emph{The Counterattack of Michelotto da Cotignola at the battle of San Romano} (c. 1455), wood panel, 182 $ × $317, Musée du Louvre, Paris}
  \end{measuredfigure}
  \label{fig:label4}
\end{figure}
```

[image]